# What distribution-shift datasets exist for ML?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, distribution, ai, artificial-intelligence

What datasets there are which contain a (labelled) distribution shift or which distribution-shifted datasets share classes?

Currently I have found some interesting results using CIFAR10 and the ImageNet subset of CINIC10, i.e. ImageNet images that correspond to the CIFAR classes. So I want to see if I can replicate these results on other datasets which have distribution shifts between them.

I know there are various MNIST datasets which have a distribution shift, but I was hoping to go for something a bit more complicated if possible.

Preferably, I would also like to do more than just add augmentations to a subset of an existing dataset to have something that is more similar to a real-world data shift.